# How can I call http request by controller adonis?

Tags: json, http-post, postman, adonis.js

I try like this :

```
class CategoryController {
  async index ({ request, response, view }) {
    const categories = await request.get('https://myapp-api.website.com/api/v2/data')
    const a = response.json(categories)
    return {
      data: a
    }
  }
}
```

My routes :

```
Route.group(()=>{
  Route.get('categories', 'CategoryController.index')
}).prefix('api/v1')
```

I try to call by postman like this : http://127.0.0.1:3333/api/v1/categories

The result is empty array `{}`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To send an http request you can use the `axios` library. Like:

```js
const axios = use('axios')
const querystring = use('querystring')

try {
     /* get('url', params) */
     const data_request = await axios.get('yourUrl', querystring.stringify({ }))
} catch(error)
{ ... }
```

Documentation : https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Thanks. But I try `return response.send(data_request)` to return the response. There exist error : `Converting circular structure to JSON
`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you give me the content of: `data_request`

Comment: @SuccessMan you need to return `response.data` instead of response. in case of this example use `data_request.data` .